# Install4j: run batch file/ script file for rollback action

Tags: java, install4j

In linux I would like my updater to run a script file for rollback action (which is actually to change some file permissions to another user not the root). So, the possible ways I could think of are:

1. Use action: "Run executable or batch file" while performing rollback and run the script as it uses the root privileges.
2. Any method to run the script or call already created "Run executable or batch file"  with root privilege from the `InstallerEventListener` while performing rollback action.
3. Use the `ProcessBuilder` inside the rollback action (which I have used for normal actions)

But form the install4j documentation I could not find any methods that can help me to do this. I was reading the documentation on [InstallerContext.runElevated](https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/context/Context.html#runElevated-com.install4j.api.context.RemoteCallable-boolean-) but it did not seem the thing I am looking for.

UPDATE:

Turns out directly running the script using `ProcessBuilder` In the "run script" action with maximum elevated privilege(root) makes the task done. But I am still interested to know if it is possible for the event listener to trigger an action from it.

Comment: Why can't you use the "Run executable or batch file" action and its "Use rollback executable" property?

Comment: but is that only valid for the particular "Run executable or batch file" action? For my case I have set an action listener which performs a rollback function which I have defined commonly for any actions. And what I am trying to achieve here is to somehow run a script in the rollback function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event listener code, you can run actions programmatically like this:

```
import com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.misc.*;

RunExecutableAction action = new RunExecutableAction();
action.setExecutable(...);
action.setWorkingDirectory(...);
// other configuration
action.execute(context);
```

To execute it with maximum privileges, execute the action like this:

```
context.runElevated(new RemoteCallable() {
    @Override
    public Serializable execute() {
        RunExecutableAction action = new RunExecutableAction();
        action.setExecutable(...);
        action.setWorkingDirectory(...);
        // other configuration
        return action.execute(context);
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: awesome!! And it will be executed with the maximum privilege?

Comment: @Ingo This is causing java.io.NotSerializableException exception. I changed the return value in runElevated to Boolean.valueOf(action.execute(context)) and still seeing the same exception.

I am creating a SetOwnerAction in my case.

Comment: The action has to be created inside the RemoteCallable, see my edit.